# TensorFlow: Efficiently read (and shuffle) samples from large files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

**Set-up**

I have several dozens of medium sized files (~1G), each containing one sample per row for a given class. In each file, samples are in non-random order, i.e. the i'th sample of file A is somewhat correlated with the i'th sample of file B, as data was samples along some axis for each class (details not important).

---

**Issue**

Reading and processing all samples in memory is not an option due to (1) the could be up to hundreds of files (2) memory footprint of each sample increases significantly after pre-processing (e.g. due to large one-hot encoding vectors).

My goal is to efficiently read samples (or batches) from disk and feed it into my tf.keras model. Further, I want to shuffle the order in which samples (or batches) are fed into the network after each epoch.

---

*How can I archive this with reasonable efficiency, i.e. such that my GPU doesn't idle during training?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, assuming you are reading TFRecord files. Specific parameters depend on the size of each example and your available resources:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
ds = (tf.data.Dataset.list_files('data_dir/*.tfrecord')
      .cache()
      .repeat()
      .shuffle(1_000)
      .interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, block_length=100,
                  # Optional
                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      .shuffle(10_000)
      .map(record_parse_function)
      .batch(32)
      .prefetch(1))
```

In any case, it is recommendable to read the [guide about `tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) and [input pipeline performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).

Comment: Thanks for providing the code and resources! Could you briefly explain what's going on in the code, especially why you are calling shuffle two times?

Comment: @bi_scholar It should be more or less readable... I list the files, cache that list (which probably doesn't make a difference but anyway), and repeat to go over the files repeatedly, then shuffle the list of files, then interleave take blocks of 100 examples from the next group of files (each group should be as big as the number of cores), then shuffle the interleaved data, then parse the examples, batch it and prefetch one batch to reduce GPU stalling. You can tweak it as needed though, maybe you don't want the first shuffle, or prefer a larger `cycle_length` in `interleave`.